# What is this symbol? A circle with an arrow joining two connections and another arrow pointing to it

Tags: symbol

The symbol is a circle with an arrow joining the two connections and another arrow in right angle pointing to it.

[image: in scheme of sensor ZK24-2 from Altpro]

What is this symbol? I see this symbol in scheme of sensor ZK24-2 from Altpro.

Comment: Might be helpful to post the context of the symbol.

Comment: If I had to guess, I’d say a voltage-controlled current source. But some context would certainly help.

Comment: I agree.VCCS ....... or a CCCS

Answer (score 2):

Due Intellectual Property and business reasons, this company does not wish to disclose much details without an NDA.   It could be a Hall Effect device with current output due variable reluctance current of rolling train wheels or other magnetic sensor that amplifies current with a transistor.

Regardless it is an obfuscation of how the Current source works except input and output share a common sink unlike the Ebers Mols model in a transistor.

So it could be a CCCS or a VCCS. You want us to guess?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without context, it looks like an adjustable constant current source to me: the arrow in the bubble is a constant current source, and the arrow pointing at the bubble is like the wiper part of a potentiometer symbol.